# How to load 1000+ items to a asp:GridView from SQL Server DB with high efficiency

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, datatable

I have a function like below that I use to return a `gridview` *(id: dgmenu)* to the end users based on their role. Note that I am not allowed to apply pagination to the gridView, all items must be seen in one page.

```
protected DataTable MenuForUserRole(string userRole) {
  DataTable dtMenus = new DataTable();
  string connectionString = constr;
  try {
    using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
      cnn.Open();
      string query = @"Select mycolumn1, mycolumn2, mycolumn3, mycolumn4m mycolumn5
                       From mytable
                       Where mykey = (select thekey from anothertable where role = @role)
                       order by myOrderColumn;
                       ";

      SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
      oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", userRole);

      using(SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(oCmd)) {
        a.Fill(dtMenus);
      }

      cnn.Close();
    }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    throw;
  }
  return dtMenus;
}
```

Usage:

```
dgMenu.DataSource = MenuForUserRole(ddlUserRoles.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
dgMenu.DataBind();
```

My issue is performance-related: some of the GridViews returned has more than 1000 items, so it takes 5-6 seconds to load the complete gridView for those users, which is unacceptable. When I search online, I couldn't find more efficient code to load a gridView from SQL Server Database. Any help or advice that might increase the load speed when there is high amount of data to the gridview would be appreciated.

Used -> Visual Studio 2017 & SQL Server 2017

Comment: Limit how many rows get returned in SQL to 200 or 300 or whatever is performant enough and then put some paging on it so they could click Next to see the next 300?

Comment: GridViews are not terribly efficient controls for record counts over 100. If there's no possibility of using pagination, just use a normal HTML table.

Comment: And as always - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Just a side note: that query itself, no need to do a subquery; that's a performance issue already. Also, I believe the issue lays within setting the actual `DataSource` itself, the reason is because of the base `BaseDataList` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedatalist?view=netframework-4.8) which is an abstract base class for data listing controls such as `DataView/DataGridView`'s. For every listing it creates a unique view per say as each listing can be different; this alone is resource heavy.

Comment: What **_possible_** business case is there for a grid with 1000+ rows of data in a single page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way would be to realize that it is a bad idea.

1000 records is *too much* for any user to deal with. 1-2 Orders of Magnitude to much. There is no human on this planet, that could work with that much data at once. This data needs to be filtered, grouped or paginated **way** more before it comes in front of a user.

And those are all operations you should not be doing past the query. Those should be done in the query itself. Retrieving data you do not want to do filtering later just adds a tone of network load, adds race conditions, Database locks and is propably slower anyway (DBMS are really good at their job!). Worse, with ASP.Net and it's shared memory it can quickly [lead to memory issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2020006/how-to-troubleshoot-out-of-memory-issues-system-outofmemoryexception-i).

Answer (score 0):

Profile your code. Understand where most of the time is spent. It could be SQL Server, it could be transmission over network, it could be binding the data to the control[s]. If it is SQL Server, we would need to see your schema to tell you how performance could be improved. Like, do you have an index on `mykey`? BTW, don't call it a **key**, key is something that uniquely identifies the record, which is obviously not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Use reporting (e.g. Reporting Services) and create a link to export the data into an excel spreadsheet.